# AWS: How to connect an elastic beanstalk environment to an ec2 instance using parse server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So, I am using parse server which is hosted on an elastic beanstalk environment and I was able to upload it successfully since the Health states that it is 'OK'. My database is hosted within my EC2 instance and I'm usually able to access it via Mongodb Compass. The problem is that my Elastic beanstalk cannot seem to read the database that is within the ec2 instance.

I know that for apps built using parse server require one to set up environment variables shown in the screenshot. So my question is, which url should I use for the database_uri? I have tried using the Public DNS (IPv4) and the Private IPs from the EC2 instance but none of them have worked. I believe that knowing this answer will successfully connect the ec2 instance to the app. I appreciate the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the EC2 instance with MongoDB and the Elastic Beanstalk instance are both in the same VPC. If that is so, then you need to use the private IP of the EC2 MongoDB instance. You will also need to open the security group rules assigned to the MongoDB instance appropriately.

Comment: Ok, firstly, thanks for the reply. Second, what are the exact security rules that I should add?

Comment: The security group on the MongoDB server should have an inbound rule to accept requests on port `27017` (or whatever port you have MongoDB listening on). The "Source" field for that rule should contain the Security Group ID of the security group Elastic Beanstalk is configured to use. That way any EC2 instances created by Elastic Beanstalk will have access to the MongoDB server because they belong to a security group that has been given access to that port.

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work. Somehow my app still isn't successfully fetching data from the database. Could there be any step I might have missed during the whole set up process?

Comment: What is the `bind_ip` setting in your MongoDB server's config?

Comment: Where can I check the bind_ip? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm kinda new to this

Comment: What I'm getting from the link is that I need to get it from my mongodb configuration file which is in  <install directory>/bin/mongod.cfg. The thing is, I do not have mongodb installed locally on my computer. It is within my ec2 instance. Can I get it from within the EC2 intance?

Comment: Yes you would have to login to the EC2 server to view the configuration files that are on the EC2 server...

Comment: Ok, I am currently on the ec2 instances page. Where exactly on the page is this configuration file located? What steps should I follow in order to get to it?

Comment: You don't get to it through your web browser. How did you install MongoDB on that server if you have no idea how to logon to that server?

Comment: I'm starting from where someone else left off. I guess I'll have to take it on with them. I highly appreciate your help though.